# Is there an instance where integrity protecting metadata is bad?

Tags: hmac, integrity

In JWEs there's a unprotected data field as well as recipients are not integrity protected. Is there a case where integrity protecting this data would be a problem? If it doesn't make a difference, why isn't the entire JWE message integrity protected?

Comment: Define "bad". It's obviously not good if you're trying to do homomorphic encryption.

Comment: What exactly is JWE?

Comment: @Maeher I'm guessing RFC 7516 (JSON Web Encryption).

Comment: @forest that's correct. I was referring to RFC 7516. With regards to bad, I mean are there any cryptographic properties that I loose, by integrity checking the recipients field. It sounds like homomorphic encryption is one, which we considered more of a potential attack vector than an advantage in our case.

Comment: JWE was designed for convenience with JSON, not for security.